# MongoDB find subdocument and sort the results

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB with a complex structure and subdocuments.
The document have an structure like this:

```
doc1 = {
    '_id': '12345678',
    'url': "http//myurl/...",
    'nlp':{
        "status": "OK",
        "entities": {
            "0": {
                "type" : "Person",
                "relevance": "0.877245",
                "text" : "Neelie Kroes"
            },
            "1": {
                "type": "Company",
                "relevance": "0.36242",
                "text": "ICANN"
            },
            "2": {
                "type": "Company",
                "relevance": "0.265175",
                "text": "IANA" 
            }
        }
    }
}


doc2 = {
    '_id': '987456321',
    'url': "http//myurl2/...",
    'nlp':{
        "status": "OK",
        "entities": {
            "0": {
                "type": "Company",
                "relevance": "0.96",
                "text": "ICANN"
            },
            "1": {
                "type" : "Person",
                "relevance": "0.36242",
                "text" : "Neelie Kroes"
            },
            "2": {
                "type": "Company",
                "relevance": "0.265175",
                "text": "IANA" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My task is to search for "type" AND "text" inside the subdocument, then sort by "relevance".
With the $elemMatch operator I'm able to perform the query:

```
db.resource.find({
    'nlp.entities': {
        '$elemMatch': {'text': 'Neelie Kroes', 'type': 'Person'}
    }
});
```

Perfect, now I have to sort all the records with entities of type "Person" and value "Neelie Kroes" by relevance descending.

I tried with a normal "sort", but, as the [manual said](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) about the sort() in $elemMatch, the result may not reflect the sort order because the sort() was applied to the elements of the array before the $elemMatch projection.

In fact, the _id:987456321 will be the first (with a relevance of 0.96, but referenced to ICANN).

How can I do, to sort my documents by matched subdocument's relevance?

P.S.: I can't change the document structure.

Comment: Is this coming out as a dump from some tool or is this how your document actually looks in the mongo shell? I say this because how you represent "entities" is as a "sub-document" and not an array. Those cannot be sorted by any standard means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted I hope your documents actually do have an array, but if $elemMatch is working for you then they should.

At any rate, you cannot sort by an element in an array using find. But there is a case where you can do this using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match the documents that you want, containing the array
    { "$match": {
        "nlp.entities": {
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "text": "Neelie Kroes", 
                "type": "Person"   
            }
        }
    }},

    // Project to "store" the whole document for later, duplicating the array
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "url": "$url",
            "nlp": "$nlp"          
        },
        "entities": "$nlp.entities"
    }},

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$entities" },

    // Match "only" the relevant entities
    { "$match": {
        "entities.text": "Neelie Kroes", 
        "entities.type": "Person"   
    }},

    // Sort on the relevance
    { "$sort": { "entities.relevance": -1 } },

    // Restore the original document form
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "url": "$_id.url",
        "nlp": "$_id.nlp"
    }}
])
```

So essentially, after doing the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) condition for documents that contained the relevant match, you then use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) "store" the original document in the `_id` field and [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) a "copy" of the "entities" array.

The next [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) "filters" the array contents to only those ones that are relevant. Then you apply the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to the "matched" documents.

As the "original" document was stored under `_id`, you use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to "restore" the structure that the document actually had to begin with.

That is how you "sort" on your matched element of an array.

Note that **if** you had multiple "matches" within an array for a parent document, then you would have to employ an additional [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to get the $max value for the "relevance" field in order to complete your sort.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. The first time it's slow, but after is very fast. Is the aggregate function stored in RAM, cache or have it other speed-up system? Thank you again.