# Sort Mongo DB reesult based on inner array of objects

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

We have the following document structure in our collection:

```
{
    Title: "Some product",
    Prices:[{
             Currency: "GBP",
             Value: 10
           },
           {
             Currency: "USD",
             Value: 15
           }
    ]
}
```

We are trying to order these documents base on price in a particular currency using the C# BSON driver:

```
sort = Builders<ProductSearchData>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.Prices.First(x=>x.Currency == currency).Value);
```

We then pass this to the collection:

```
        var results = await Collection.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<ProductSearchData>
        {
            Sort =  sort,
            Skip = page*pageSize,
            Limit =  pageSize
        });
```

This however isn't giving the correct sort order. Instead values seem to come back randomly. Is the above syntax correct or should we be querying in a different way?

If we do a simpler sort, e.g.

```
sort = Builders<ProductSearchData>.Sort.Descending(x => x.Title);
```

Everything works correctly.

From logging in Mongo we seem to be getting these two queries:

```
 "{ "find" : "ProductSearch", "filter" : { "Prices" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Currency" : 10, "Value" : { "$gte" : 0, "$lte" : 10000 } } }, "IsActive" : true }, "sort" : { "Value" : 1 }, "skip" : 0, "limit" : 10, "$db" : "MyForest_Data", "lsid" : { "id" : CSUUID("d4caa989-9493-41a7-bcde-81f198beda7a") } }"



{ "aggregate" : "ProductSearch", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "Prices" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Currency" : 10, "Value" : { "$gte" : 0, "$lte" : 10000 } } }, "IsActive" : true } }, { "$group" : { "_id" : 1, "n" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }], "cursor" : { }, "$db" : "MyForest_Data", "lsid" : { "id" : CSUUID("d4caa989-9493-41a7-bcde-81f198beda7a") } }
```

Comment: What kind of query it generates if you enable profiler on mongodb side? Generally speaking ascending sort by array field will use element with minimal value to compare with other documents. The only thing is that you have some logic within .Ascending() and I wonder how it is translated to mongo query.

Comment: I doubt that your complex sorting condition will make it into the json-ish query that Mongo understands. Did you consider SelectMany ( $unwind ) stage ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added in a copy of the queries we are getting

Comment: @DimaG I looked at this but I wasn't sure how to actually use this (my lacking Mongo knowledge)

Comment: One of the approach is to create a custom field based on the currency (using $addField) and apply sort order on the custom field. Please Check this link [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256185/mongodb-sort-array-objects-within-array-using-expression)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
collection.AsQueryable()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Prices, (x, pr) => new { T = x.Title, V = pr.Value, C = pr.Currency } )
            .Where(x => x.C == "GBP")
            .OrderBy(x => x.V)
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(100)
```

- skip & take for paging...

Comment: So you know the equivalent to this using Builders? we aren't using linq in our solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example without AsQueryable. But it should be something like: collection.Aggregate()
                .Unwind("Prices")
                .Project(/*Projection builder here*/)
                .Match(/*currency filter builder here*/)
                .Sort(/*soft builder*/)
                .Skip(0)
                .Limit(100)

This is what I was trying to use: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/driver/crud/linq/#unwind

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer that solves the problem but rather an explanation of what happens:

The query that reaches the database is

```
"find" : "ProductSearch", 
"filter" : { 
    "Prices" : { 
        "$elemMatch" : { 
            "Currency" : 10, 
            "Value" : { "$gte" : 0, "$lte" : 10000 } 
        } 
    }, 
    "IsActive" : true 
}, 
"sort" : { "Value" : 1 }, 
"skip" : 0, 
"limit" : 10,
```

It searches for documents that have price between 0 and 10,000 in specific currency, then it sorts by top-level field `Value`. My guess is it not what OP intended and there are no such field at all so the documents are returned in natural order.

A quick search brings [MongoDB find subdocument and sort the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751210/mongodb-find-subdocument-and-sort-the-results) which seems a reasonable way to sort by the matching subdocument.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the suggestions by the other two answers but couldn't find a clean way to do an UnWind command that allows us to use Builders in the MongoDB C# library. Additionally on reflection we were worried about the performance impact of MongoDB having to perfom the unwind in memory for each query.

Instead we decided to do a "unwind" the Prices field during the indexing process. When we index the Product into the search collection we create one record for each currency the product has. We also set a group ID which allows us to identify all related records for cleanup:

```
        var results = new IndexingData();

        results.GroupId = source.Id.ToString();

        foreach (var price in source.Prices)
        {
            var searchData =  new ProductSearchRecord()
            {
                Id=  $"{source.Id}{price.Currency}",
                GroupId =  source.Id.ToString(),
                Title =  source.Title,
                Price= price,
            };

            results.Records.Add(searchData);
        }


        return results;
```

Inserting into the collection:

```
        var indexingData = GetRecords(source);

        await Collection.DeleteManyAsync(x => x.GroupId == indexingData.GroupId);

        foreach (var record in indexingData.Records)
        {
            await Collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == record.Id, record,
                new UpdateOptions() {IsUpsert = true});
        }
```